# Create table from another table in Spark

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have some CSV files and I created a table in `spark-sql` using this [link](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv). Let's call the table as `T1`.

However, when I try to create another table from it, using

```
create table T2 as seelct * from T1;
```

I get an error: **columns has 42 elements while columns.type has 27 elements**

The reason to create another Table is that I can't access contents of `T1` from Hive.